# Geometry geografic transformation with OGR, OSR - UTM to Degree

Tags: geometry, ogr, latitude-longitude, utm, osgeo

I am trying make a geotransformation from UTM coordinates to decimal degree coordinates, but i have only zeros as result... I must be missing something, i already take a lock on other users codes but i can't find my bug. I would apreciate a little help here!

Those are the shapefiles i used (i uploaded in Google drive):
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1URP8UxjNxaI8XO-qNrzWb8-lNA1ZDCBe?usp=sharing

```
sentinel_grid_shp_path = r'grid_s2.shp'
shp_path = r'zonal_3_zones_1000_m2_filtering_L4.shp'

from osgeo import ogr, osr

# OSGEO Driver
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

##### datasource 01 - 4674
dataSource = driver.Open(sentinel_grid_shp_path, 0)
dataSourceLayer = dataSource.GetLayer()

# Get DATUM information
sourceDatumRef = dataSourceLayer.GetSpatialRef()
# Get EPGS code
a = sourceDatumRef.ExportToWkt()[sourceDatumRef.ExportToWkt().rfind("AUTHORITY") + 9:].replace("]]", "]")
b = a.replace("[", "").replace('"', '').replace("]", "")
### EPGS code
sourceDatumRefEPGS = int(list(map(str, b.split(",")))[1]) ### 4674

# Spatial ref 4674
outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(sourceDatumRefEPGS)

##### datasource 02 - 32721
dataReceiver = driver.Open(shp_PATH, 1)
dataReceiverLayer = dataReceiver.GetLayer()

# Get DATUM information
receiverDatumRef = dataReceiverLayer.GetSpatialRef()
# Get EPGS code
a = receiverDatumRef.ExportToWkt()[receiverDatumRef.ExportToWkt().rfind("AUTHORITY") + 9:].replace("]]", "]")
b = a.replace("[", "").replace('"', '').replace("]", "")
### EPGS code
receiverDatumRefEPGS = int(list(map(str, b.split(",")))[1]) ### 32721

# Spatial Ref 32721
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(receiverDatumRefEPGS)

# Definition of geotrnaformation
geo_transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)


### Parsing througout layer features and applying geotransformation
for feature in dataReceiverLayer:
    geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    centroid_wkt = geom.Centroid().ExportToWkt()
    centroid_geometry = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(centroid_wkt)

    # GEOTRANSFORMATION - ONLY '0' AS RESULT!!!
    print(centroid_geometry.Transform(geo_transform))

del feature, geom, centroid_wkt

# Excuding and deleting all objects 

driver = None

dataSource = None
dataReceiver = None

dataSourceLayer = None
dataReceiverLayer = None

sourceDatumRef = None
receiverDatumRef = None

sourceDatumRefEPGS = None
receiverDatumRefEPGS = None

inSpatialRef = None
outSpatialRef = None

a = None
b = None

centroid_geometry = None

ogr = None
```

Comment: Please add some example data for which your code returns zeros.

Comment: Sorry about it, i put available (on my google drive) the shapefiles that i am working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug... Once u have the centroid geometry as Wkt, for instance:

```
centroid_geometry = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(centroid_wkt)
```

All you need have in mind is that u need first make the geotransformation, and after that u can print it, step by step... as follow:

```
centroid_geometry.Transform(geo_transform)
print(centroid_geometry)
```